# How do I find the resulting vector?

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

I am coding a Minecraft plugin and I am trying to figure out how to get the exact position the player is looking (basically a straight line from the players head). I dont need any help with coding it I just need some help with the math. Essentially I am looping in half a meter increments till I reach the nearest thing but the main trouble I am having is calculating where the player is looking at. Minecraft uses X, Y, and Z coordinates as well as pitch and yaw. Y coordinates corresponds to vertical position in the world while pitch corresponds to how much the head tilts up and down. When the player looks directly at the floor the pitch will be 90 and when the player looks straight up in the air their pitch will be -90 meaning a pitch of 0 is looking straight ahead. The yaw corresponds to the players rotational motion and it goes from 180 to -180 making the 360 degrees of rotation. Now if a player has a yaw of 0 and they walk forward this would represent the player strictly moving in the positive Z direction which makes a yaw of 180 / -180 denote the player moving in the negative Z direction. Lastly a yaw of -90 denotes a positive X and 90 denotes a negative X. Now with that out of the way I can show you what I have.

```
    Player p = e.getPlayer();
    Location origin = p.getEyeLocation();
    double x = origin.getX();
    double y = origin.getY();
    double z = origin.getZ();
    System.out.println("ORIGIN: " + origin);
    for(double i=0; i<=4; i+=0.5) {
        double yRadians = Math.toRadians(90 - origin.getPitch());
        y = (origin.getY() - (i * Math.cos(yRadians)));
        double zRadians = Math.toRadians(origin.getYaw());
        z = (origin.getZ() + (i * Math.cos(zRadians)));
        double xRadians = Math.toRadians(90 - origin.getYaw());
        x = (origin.getX() - (i * Math.cos(xRadians)));

        System.out.println("X:" + x + " Y:" + y + " Z:" + z);
    }
    Location craftLocation = new Location(p.getWorld(), x, y, z);
    craftLocation.getBlock().setType(Material.DIAMOND_BLOCK);
```

Anyways this works fine when I keep my pitch close to 0 (looking straight ahead) but the more I look up or down the further off my calculations get. I know that my Y calculations are right but the problem is that I need my X and Z coordinates to take into account the Y because just logically thinking about it when I look higher up in the air my X and Z vectors should become shorter (by this I mean it will take a larger distance for the vector to reach an object due to it not going straight) because right now I am just taking in account my pitch. So how can I correctly shorten the magnitudes of X and Z in order for this to always create a straight line from the players head? For the sake of the math you can just assume I (the distance from the player) will just be 4 meters since I can always change it later.

Comment: Try looking at the page on spherical coordinates: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system. I think what you need to do is, for z and x, to multiply i * Math.cos(zRadians) * Math.sin(yRadians), though I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do. It looks like i is the distance out from the center, so i*sin(yRadians) would be the projection of i onto the X-Z plane, i.e., the distance on that plane.

Comment: Actually yea that does work thank you!! I tried doing it with cos of yRadians lmao.